# Pex – test input generator

Tags: testing, pex

I have created sample method in c#.I use Pex add-in in Visual Studio 2010. I have to test my sample method with few tests.I should do this automatically not manually.I read a lot of articles about PUT(Parameterized Unit Testing) with Pex.I dont't understand how Pex automatically create test inputs.I am not really good at programming so I don't do that myself. Can anybody suggest me some good tutorial for beginners?

Answer (score 0):

The official website offers not only docs but also comprehensive tutorials.

You can also try out [Pex4Fun](http://pex4fun.com/) which is a web-based Pex-frontend.